# Background image not showing up in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, background-image

My custom background image is not showing up in AngularJS. Can't figure out why.

When I test `$scope.setBackground` in console, I get Object `{background-image: "url(image.jpg)"}`

Controller:

```
app.controller('backgroundImageCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.setBackground = {
        'background-image' : 'url(image.jpg)'
    };
})
```

HTML:

```
<script type = "text/ng-template" id="/page.html" ng-controller="backgroundImageCtrl" ng-style="setBackground">
    <div>
    ...
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: you should use setBackground in div that use your template.

Comment: I think that it's because the `background-image` is on the `template` tag. It's should be on a inner element.

Comment: is your question answered?

Comment: @MoshFeu that's exactly it, I put the controller and ng-style into the div and works now

Comment: @MoshFeu but what is the reason that I have to place ng-controller and ng-style in an inner element?

Comment: That's because you can't style `script` tag. Also, as I know, the template engine take the **inner** content of the `script` tag and put it wherever it should. So, those attributes `ng-controller` and `ng-style` will not affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution as suggested by @Mosh Feu, simply place `ng-controller="backgroundImageCtrl"` and `ng-style="setBackground"` in an inner div

```
<script type = "text/ng-template" id="/page.html">
    <div ng-controller="backgroundImageCtrl" ng-style="setBackground">
    ...
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.style= {};
    $scope.setBackground = function (date) {
      $scope.style = {
        'background-image': 'url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/10821c595d354140ee66f2a04fb11b7c?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1")'
      }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="setBackground()">set background</button>
    <div ng-style="style">see the background</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use setBackground in div that use your template. try like this.

```
<div ng-include src="/page.html" ng-style="setBackground"></div>
```

```js
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.

  when('/addStudent', {
    templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
    controller: 'AddStudentController'
  }).

  when('/viewStudents', {
    templateUrl: 'viewStudents.htm',
    controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
  }).

  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/addStudent'
  });
}]);

mainApp.controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
  $scope.setBackground = {
    'background-image' : 'url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/10821c595d354140ee66f2a04fb11b7c?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1)'
  };
});

mainApp.controller('ViewStudentsController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "This page will be used to display all the students";
  $scope.setBackground = {
    'background-image' : 'url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6755dcaf172d19cb9976bedcc56cfed3?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1)'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "mainApp">
  <p><a href = "#addStudent">Add Student</a></p>
  <p><a href = "#viewStudents">View Students</a></p>
  <div ng-view ng-style="setBackground"></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="addStudent.htm">
    <h2> Add Student </h2>
    {{message}}
  </script>

  <script type = "text/ng-template" id="viewStudents.htm">
    <h2> View Students </h2>
    {{message}}
  </script>
</div>
```